# Transfer function of RLC circuit without input source?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: fig1]

Let's say you have an RLC series circuit with an initial voltage across the capacitor and no initial current, and no input voltage driving the RLC circuit, that is: $$v_\text{input}(t)=0$$

The output of the RLC circuit $$V_\text{output}(s)$$ is the voltage across the capacitor.

How would you find the transfer function H(s) of this circuit, since its doesn't have an input?

$$H(s) = V_\text{output}(s) / V_\text{input}(s)$$

The textbook says the transfer function is just:

$$H(s) = V_\text{output}(s)$$

Isn't the Laplace transform of a zero volt input voltage source equal to zero?

$$V_\text{input}(s) = \mathscr{L}[0~~volts] = 0$$

Therefore:

$$H(s) = V_\text{output}(s)/0 = \infty$$

Just curious how they get the result:

$$H(s) = V_\text{output}(s)$$

Answer (score 1):

An input can be regarded as the voltage across the switch before it closes. This voltage has been established as the voltage the capacitor was initially charged with. You could even make a case for the switch being an actual DC voltage source that becomes 0 volts at the time the switch closes thus, the series RLC is driven by a step change input equivalent to -Vc.

Comment: is that because i(t=0)=0, therefore there is no voltage dropped across resister and inductor at time zero, and all voltage of the switch goes to the capacitor?

Comment: Correct, at t equals 0 there is no current flow.

Comment: then switch is an impulse voltage $$V_c(0)\delta(t)$$ equal to capacitor's initial voltage.

Comment: Are you aware that formally accepting answers to questions you’ve raised when the answer is good is the punitive price for showing respect in these parts. I’m saying that because I noticed you hadn’t done that so far. You probably were not aware of that maybe or, maybe you were?

Comment: No the input voltage is a step.

Comment: does that mean $$V_c(0)u(-t)$$?

Comment: Use words and note my earlier comment please.

Comment: @Andyaka Yeah. Now that you point it out, I see pico doesn't ever select answers. Well, there is the joy of having a dialog and maybe helping....

Comment: I gave you an upvote...I just don't like clicking the check because it locks the question...

Comment: It doesn’t lock the question and I’m not asking for anything on this question; it’s your previous questions that should probably have some formal acceptance.

Comment: @pico Selecting an answer to your question helps others not waste their time reading your questions and/or then adding more answers to your question. It's the respectful thing to do. Not because it gives points to someone. Who cares? But because there are hundreds of others (now, next week, and years from now) who may yet squander their time wondering if you need further/better help. And you should respect ***their*** time. It's the considerate thing to do. That is, if you feel you have an adequate answer. Of course, if you are still waiting for better, feel free to leave it.